# Details about hardware requirements for ubuntu touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, hardware, tablet

I am considering getting a new Android tablet and installing Ubuntu Touch on it.
On the [Ubuntu "Operators and OEMs"](http://www.ubuntu.com/tablet/operators-and-oems) page, there is a table of the hardware requirements to run Ubuntu Touch on a tablet.  Here is the table:

```
                   Entry level consumer     High-end Ubuntu
                   Ubuntu tablet            enterprise tablet
Processor arch.    Dual-core Cortex A15     Quad-core A15 or Intel x86
Memory             2GB preferred            4GB preferred
Flash storage      8GB minimum              8GB minimum
Screen size        7-10 inch                10-12 inch
Multi-touch        4 fingers                4-10 fingers
Full desktop       No                       Yes
convergence
```

**So, my question is:**
What is the difference between the "Entry level consumer Ubuntu tablet" and the "High-end Ubuntu enterprise tablet" and do I care?  And what is this "Full desktop convergence" feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ubuntu Touch** is a variant of Ubuntu for smartphones and tablets. Higher-end Ubuntu smartphones will be able to run a full Ubuntu desktop when connected to a monitor and keyboard, a feature pioneered in Ubuntu for Android.

**Ubuntu for Android** is a variant of Ubuntu designed to run on Android phones, which provides a windowing application environment and desktop environment of Ubuntu when the phone is docked to lapdock. It is expected to come preloaded on several phones.

<sup>**Source:** [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29#Variants)</sup>

Comment: So, if I flash an existing Android tablet (like the Nexus 7), I will be able to dock it and use as a desktop with a window-type interface or use it as a tablet with full-screen apps, correct?

Comment: While mid-range phones can deliver a perfect Android experience, it takes high-end horsepower to drive a phone and a desktop at the same time. **Only** newer multi-core processors (dual-core or better) are up to the job. Source: http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/ubuntu-for-android

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Your adding sources on your answers is really helpful.